# extracting data from fetched tweets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tweepy

I fetched some tweets with tweepy api and saved them in a txt file. Now I want to extract them into data frame with panda, like, the content of the tweet and maybe the date. 
Any ideas how I can do it ?
Btw. I'm really new in python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: btw. I need the data for my LDA model in Python

Comment: Please share the input data example, code, expected output, so someone can help you.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47925828/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-using-tweepy

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of your txt file,your approach may vary but overall:
You want to open the file in python, read it (probably line by line), and parse it into a panda dataframe.

for example to extract a line of your document:

```
file = open(“testfile.txt”, “r”) 
for line in file: 
   # do something (like parsing) on your line.
```

Comment: what I actually want is to fetch the stream tweets and pre process them for lda model analyses.