# Determine If a Tweet is a Retweet or Not

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am trying to find whether a certain tweet is an original tweet or a retweet.

I tried using `retweeted_status`, but it does not appear in the JSON even that the status is a retweet.

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47612822/how-to-create-pandas-dataframe-from-twitter-search-api/47943827#47943827 where I create a pandas dataframe to store twitter data. One of the created columns reveals if the stored twitter is a retweet or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter API: Check if a tweet is a retweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869688/twitter-api-check-if-a-tweet-is-a-retweet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tweet is a retweet, then the value of `retweeted_status` will contain the JSON object of the original tweet.

From the [Twitter API Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json):

> If you are working with a Retweet object, then that object will contain two Tweet objects, complete with two User objects.  The Tweet that was Retweeted is referred to as the 'original' Tweet and is displayed under the 'retweeted_status' key.

Also from [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object):

> Retweets can be distinguished from typical Tweets by the existence of a `retweeted_status` attribute. This attribute contains a representation of the original Tweet that was retweeted.

Example (copied from the pages above) of original tweet JSON object skeleton (does not have a `retweeted_status` key):

```
{
  "tweet": {
    "user": {
      ...
    },
    "place": {
      ...
    },
    "entities": {
      ...
    },
    "extended_entities": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Example of a Retweet JSON object skeleton (has the `retweeted_status` key):

```
{
  "tweet": {
    "user": {

    },
    "retweeted_status": {
      "tweet": {
        "user": {

        },
        "place": {

        },
        "entities": {

        },
        "extended_entities": {

        }
      },

    },
    "place": {

    },
    "entities": {

    },
    "extended_entities": {

    }
  }
}
```